# Correct Date and Time Columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, adjustment

I have a timezone mismatch I need to correct in a table. All dates and times before unix timestamp 1253568477 need to have 5 hours added to their values to make them equal GMT.

I have the following columns...

`date` (data type `date`), off by -5 hours

`time` (data type `time`), off by -5 hours

`timestamp` (data type `int`), this column is the correct time

The reason the timezones are off is because of the way I was setting the values when inserting the rows...

```
$sql = "insert into email_opens (userid, email, serial, date, time, timestamp) values (
'$userid',
'$opened_by',
'$serial_number',
now(),
now()',
'".gmmktime()."'
)";
```

The `now()` value was using the server timezone (eastern) whereas the `gmmktime` value specified GMT. I have since corrected this query to always use GMT.

Is there a way I can add 5 hours to both `time` and `date` columns for those rows where timestamp < 1253568477 in one batch query?

Clarification:

My goal is to update each incorrect row in the table with the correct time by adding 5 hours to each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
UPDATE mail_opens SET date = DATE_ADD(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), INTERVAL 5 HOUR), time = DATE_ADD(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), INTERVAL 5 HOUR);
```

And then you probably need this:

```
<?php
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>";
    $addhours = strtotime('+5 hour');
    echo $addhours."<br>";
    $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $addhours);
    echo $newdate;
?>
```

So, using that:

```
<?php
$addhours = strtotime('+5 hour');
$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $addhours);
$sql = "insert into email_opens (userid, email, serial, date, time, timestamp) values (
'$userid',
'$opened_by',
'$serial_number',
'$newdate',
'$newdate',
'".gmmktime()."'
)";
?>
```

Comment: Since I want to update existing rows, I could turn this into a looped UPDATE statement. But is there a MySQL statement that could do this without the need for PHP?

Comment: nice! was messing with the date_add function, but was missing your concat portion! good thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

sure, work out the time you corrected the problem so you know only to update records that have a value less than the unix timestamp of your timezone change.

Then update the field and add 60 * 60 * 5 (5 hours in seconds) to those records.

So, your query would be the following:

```
UPDATE email_opens SET timestamp = (timestamp + 18000) WHERE timestamp < 1253568477;
```

Cool.

Comment: That's almost it! ..but you're adding 120 hours to the already correct timestamp value, when I need to add 5 *hours* to the date and time values.

Comment: You're right, i was thinking 5 days instead of 5 hours! woops : /